# How can I find the shortest cycle in a Directed, Weighted Graph?

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I am looking for the easiest way to find the shortest cycle in a graph.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could use a shortest-path algorithm for the path between a node and itself, and do this for every node.  Sounds pretty darn easy... (it might not be efficient though)

Answer (score -1):

```
"By the power of Google!" - Heman
```

You can find it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: Is the Floyd-Warshall particularly suited for finding minimal cycles?  I don't see immediately how it's superior to, say, Djikstra's.

Comment: No reason, im just saying its easier to google it. That is the result i got from copying the question into google... (Yes I know of Dijkstras), its an inane question for SO...