# How to find the shortest directed cycle in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

From https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/

> 40. **Shortest directed cycle.** Given a digraph, design an algorithm to find a directed cycle with the minimum number of edges (or report that
>       the graph is acyclic). The running time of your algorithm should be
>       proportional to E V in the worst case.

The solution is found here: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/ShortestDirectedCycle.java.html

```
public ShortestDirectedCycle(Digraph G) {
    Digraph R = G.reverse();
    length = G.V() + 1;
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        BreadthFirstDirectedPaths bfs = new BreadthFirstDirectedPaths(R, v);
        for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
            if (bfs.hasPathTo(w) && (bfs.distTo(w) + 1) < length) {
                length = bfs.distTo(w) + 1;
                cycle = new Stack<Integer>();
                for (int x : bfs.pathTo(w))
                    cycle.push(x);
                cycle.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The solution makes sense to me, except for the first line `G.reverse()`. Why? Does it have anything to do with Topological sort?

There are quite a few questions on SO regarding finding all cycles in a Digraph, but I'm assuming there's a better way than finding all cycles and comparing their lengths. There are some questions regarding finding the shortest directed cycle, but none has an acceptable answer.

[How can I find the shortest cycle in a Directed, Weighted Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5700148/839733)

[Find the Shortest Cycle in Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30614896/839733)

[Finding shortest cycles in directed or undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47795348/839733) (this one is for undirected graph)

I also found a [paper](https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234247/Winter2003-2004/ho/WCFiles/Girth.pdf) that uses BFS, but the pseudocode presented can't be used to reconstruct the path, only to find the length of the shortest cycle.

Comment: This question is actually asked at Coursera Algorithms Part 2 course. Considering that the course and your link are from the same author, this answer is correct. I see the main idea of this solution: if you have some neighbor in a straight graph and you can somehow reach it in a reversed graph, it is a cycle. I think the most similar algorithm is Kosaraju which reverses a graph to find strongly connected components.

Comment: @vorrtex _"This question is actually asked at Coursera Algorithms Part 2 course. Considering that the course and your link are from the same author..."_ is that somehow relevant? how does it matter where else this question is asked, and by who?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`G.reverse()` is a digraph that's the same as `G` *except* that each edge is reversed; so, for example, if `G` has an edge from `v` to `w`, then `G.reverse()` has an edge from `w` to `v`.

Since `bfs` is taken from `G.reverse()` and `v`, `bfs.hasPathTo(w)` means "whether `G` has a path *from* `w` *to* `v`", and `bfs.distTo(w)` means "the length of `G`'s path from `w` to `v`". (If `bfs` were taken from `G` instead of `G.reverse()`, it would detect paths going the other way.)

So the cycle-finding algorithm it's using is: for each edge (`v`,`w`) in `G`, test whether `G` has a path from `w` back to `v`.

Topological sorting is not involved.

Comment: Why not just check for `bfs.hasPathTo(v)` for every `v`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: I imagine that `bfs.hasPathTo(v)`, `bfs.distTo(v)`, and `bsf.pathTo(v)` would always return `true`, `0`, and the empty path (respectively). Of course, it could be changed to ignore the empty path; the code that you've posted only makes sense, IMHO, if `BreadthFirstDirectedPaths` is also used for other things.